# Javascript/html : Two input range field balance scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I make these two input range fields balance to maximum 100, that when I move the first input field range the second should be adjusting too, vice versa. I mean that it should be proportional both sides like balance scale.

Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/jsm4s2oz/1/

```
//First input range

<output name="judge_rangeOutput" id="judge_rangeOutput">75</output>
<input type="range"  name="judge_range" id="judge_range" min="0" max="100" value="75" oninput="judge_rangeOutput.value = judge_range.value"><br/>


//Second input range
<output name="preJudge_rangeOutput" id="preJudge_rangeOutput">25</output>
<input type="range" name="prejudges_range" id="prejudges_range" min="0" max="100" value="25" oninput="preJudge_rangeOutput.value = prejudges_range.value ">
```

Comment: Set a change handler on each slider. Subtract the value from 100 and set the other slider to that.

Comment: @Barmar can you give me an example, I trying to get since early my code not working at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `input` handler, in addition to changing the `<output>` field for the same slider, also change the value of the other slider and the other `<output>` to `100 - this.value`.

```js
$("#judge_range").on("input", function() {
  $("#judge_rangeOutput").val(this.value);
  $("#prejudges_range").val(100 - this.value);
  $("#preJudge_rangeOutput").val(100 - this.value);
});
$("#prejudges_range").on("input", function() {
  $("#preJudge_rangeOutput").val(this.value);
  $("#judge_range").val(100 - this.value);
  $("#judge_rangeOutput").val(100 - this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
First input range
<output name="judge_rangeOutput" id="judge_rangeOutput">75</output>
<input type="range" name="judge_range" id="judge_range" min="0" max="100" value="75">
<br/>Second input range
<output name="preJudge_rangeOutput" id="preJudge_rangeOutput">25</output>
<input type="range" name="prejudges_range" id="prejudges_range" min="0" max="100" value="25">
```

Comment: How would this change for 3 or more range inputs instead of 2?

Comment: How would they be related?

Comment: Let's say you have three range elements whose values should add up to 100, with what formula do you balance the other two when you change one of them?

Comment: You could calculate the old ratio between the other two inputs. Then subtract the current input's value from 100, and multiply that by the appropriate ratio.